# Is it possible to get the Program Files or Windows directory location without using environment variables

Tags: c#

I'm currently launching Notepad and Internet Explorer from my application using `Process.Start()` as follows:

```
Process.Start("notepad.exe", textFileName);
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", htmlFileName);
```

...which gets the paths from the environment.  A security review identified this as a concern because an attacker could tamper with the environment to cause a different binary to be launched than the one intended. Recommendations were made to set `processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false` and to use an absolute path.

Instead of hard coding absolute paths of `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`, I'm wondering if there's a good way to get the locations that doesn't rely on environment variables.  The conventional .net approach doesn't appear to be a suitable option; because the name of the the [System.Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration strongly implies that any attack of the type being considered would result in it returning tainted results.

Comment: PS To head off the inevitable query, htmlFileName is a legacy format that I can't change and which won't work in other browsers; so yes I do have to force IE regardless of the systems default browser.

Comment: I don't think %windir% can be tampered without consequences is it?

Comment: If someone gains enough privileges to tamper with environment variables like those, you have very little defense. What blocks this user to directly change these two programs?

Comment: Is launching a different binary actually a security hole? If an outside attacker is able to change what would be launched, they've pretty much owned your box anyway.

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure about that; but I am certain that translating "a hacker that's able to pwn environment variables has so many other ways of pwning my app that it doesn't matter" into suitable bureaucratese would be far more unpleasant than just hardcoding a pair of paths that will be constant unless someone is doing something weird.  (eg Windows dual boot on a single drive will put one copy somewhere other than C:\Windows\).  Especially when the first level customer contact doesn't have the technical skills to understand if his IA people are being irrational paranoid.

Comment: Why are bureaucrats auditing your code for security?

Comment: Well, if you're going to hard-code a path and ignore edge cases, you might as well go ahead with what you have above, right?

Comment: `SpecialFolder` is most likely wrapped around [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx), rather than accessing environment variables.

Comment: I have no reason to question the technical competence of the people who did the code review; but the customer is a very large bureaucracy.  Meeting their IA requirements follows directly from what they are.  *sigh*

Comment: @Blorgbeard That looks promising if true; but I'd need to check the current .net framework code to be sure.  The .net API dates back to .net 1.1 which would run on NT4 while SHGetKnownFolderPath was only added in Vista.

Comment: Are you able to ask questions of the code reviewers? [GetFolderPath](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/eae27f70eff37268.html) does indeed call SHGetKnownFolderPath. I would go with that.

Comment: There are not constant paths to those folders.  Process.Start is the appropriate method to use.  On my systems, those files are not located at your hard coded paths you have listed, and I'd toss whatever software you are writing out if you hard-coded them that way.

Comment: Well, if you feel like digging into the registry you can go hunt down the program signatures in there...but digging then you'll get a "Whatif the hackers hack your registry".  At which point your answer should be, "The computer is hosed at that point and needs a full re-install anyway".  For that matter, they could just replace the hard coded path for Notepad.exe with their own code, particularly if they are already tricking your environment...

Comment: @RobertMcKee You can pass a "default path" flag (forgot what it's value is) to SHGetKnownFolderPath, and it will ignore any customization you have done.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think I have an email address for the auditor I can try when I'm back in the office; not having tried asking anything technical in the past I don't know how responsive he'd be.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I know the defaults can be changed; which is why I'm looking for an alternative.  Since this this will never run on anything except boxes they own and have locked down; so if I get back:  "We'd never change the MS defaults.  You must hard code the path."; at the end of the day it won't be anything worse than:  `//Done at the insistence of the customer`

Comment: @DanNeely Not the simplest way but perhaps holding a list of OS/application/version/hash and checking the list to see if one of the hash's match before executing it. Giving your goal is to really know if that application is not what you think it is. I don't really see any other way even if the compromise your environment variables with the hash you wouldn't execute something that shouldn't be?

Comment: Dan, I do believe that ultimately all methods of looking it up would go back to the registry keys, as that is authoritative source.  But for the same reasons the environment can get tainted, so can the registry, so you would be buying yourself very little security by bypassing the higher level functions and going to the registry directly.  Given your requirements, it may just be the best solution to hard code it.  Personally don't agree with it, but the customer is always right.  As per my system, it wasn't "changed", it was installed that way.  My Windows directory is on S: not C:.

Comment: @DanNeely Is your bureaucracy running AD? It should be trivial to implement a group policy to restrict access to which programs a user can/can't run. Worst case scenario, a malicious user "attacks" your system by redirecting special folders and opens _htmlFileName_ in the wrong (but still approved) application.